# How do I print factorials without using a loop?

Tags: java, recursion, factorial

I made a recursive method to calculate factorials, but in the main method I have used a for loop to calculate the list of factorials. Is there a way to calculate a list of factorials without using a loop in the main method?

Code:

```
public class FactInt {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int n = 1; n < 11; n++)
            System.out.println(factorial(n));
    }
    //Calculates the factorial of integer n
    public static int factorial(int n) {
        if (n == 0)
            return 1;
        else 
            return n*factorial(n-1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on exactly what you mean by "calculate a list", but this prints the same thing:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    factorial(10);
}
//Calculates the factorial of integer n
public static int factorial(int n) {
    if (n == 0)
        return 1;
    else {
        int newVal = n*factorial(n-1);
        System.out.println(newVal);
        return newVal;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Plasmarob It would print the factorials.

Comment: @Plasmarob You're incorrect. But it *would* leave out the printing of the base case.

Comment: You could put a `println(1)` in the first `if` statement. Since the original code started with `n = 1`, they actually do print the same thing, as you can see at these two links: http://ideone.com/RYdKWq http://ideone.com/JBIfQ8

Comment: Ah; I see! I think, formally speaking, the base case here is wrong then, but it has the same effect. (n == 1 is the appropriate base case for a factorial.)

Comment: The only problem that I am having now is that I am printing the last factoral twice for some reason.

Comment: @NathanielFord factorial(0) is 1, so the code as-is is actually valid.

Comment: @user1730357 Do you have `System.out.println(factorial(10));`? You don't need to print that value, with the code how I have it here.

Comment: @TimS. Actually, I don't get the same result using your code in comparison of what the original code prints ... Am I missing something?

Comment: @Paolo you can see the outputs of [the original code](http://ideone.com/JBIfQ8) and of [my code at ideone](http://ideone.com/RYdKWq). They are the same.

Comment: I had forgotten factorial was defined at 0, and the set-theory explanation was a useful thing for me to review! Thanks! I might say, though, that given that the original output is slightly off. *shrug*

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you don't want to use a loop, but here's a couple ideas:

**Unroll the loop yourself.**

```
System.out.println(factorial(1));
System.out.println(factorial(2));
// ...
System.out.println(factorial(11));
```

**Make another recursive method and call it from `main`.**

```
public static void factorials(int n)
{
    if (n >= 11) return;
    System.out.println(factorial(n));
    factorials(n + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I would want to say you can't or more like well why would you, but well if you really want to, you could do it like this.

```
public class FactInt {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        factorial(10);
    }
    //Calculates the factorial of integer n
    public static int factorial(int n) {
        final int calc;

        if (n == 0) { calc = 1; }
        else { calc = n * factorial(n - 1); }

        System.out.println(calc);

        return calc;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a method say getFactorial(int num) as follows. Move your for loop inside that method and call that method from main.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num = 11;
   getFactorial(num);
}

public static void getFactorial(int num){
    for (int n = 1; n < num; n++)
        System.out.println(factorial(n));
}
//Calculates the factorial of integer n
public static int factorial(int n) {
    if (n == 0)
        return 1;
    else 
        return n*factorial(n-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use recursion again like this!

```
public class FactInt {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        factorialList(1, 10);
    }
    //Calculates the factorial of integer n
    public static int factorial(int n) {
        if (n == 0)
            return 1;
        else 
            return n*factorial(n-1);
    }

    public static void factorialList(int min, int max) {
        if (min != max)
            factorialList(min, max-1);
        System.out.println(factorial(max));
    }
}
```